# Django shell won't use ipython

Tags: python, django, ipython

when I run python manage.py shell, it uses just an ordinary python not iPython.

How do I make it run iPython.

P.S. I think iPython is installed in the virtaulenv

Comment: You think? Why not check it by running `ipython` in virtualenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

If you would like to specify either IPython or bpython as your interpreter if you have both installed you can specify an alternative interpreter interface with the -i or --interface options like so:

IPython:

django-admin shell -i ipython
django-admin shell --interface ipython